# Select All Text in INPUT=TEXT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

The following code is doing this: when user press [Enter], it will jump/switch to the next TEXTBOX.

```
$(function () {
    $('input:text:first').focus();
    var $inp = $('input:text');
    $inp.bind('keydown', function (e) {
        //var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode);
        var key = e.which;
        if (key == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var nxtIdx = $inp.index(this) + 1;
            var nextTextBox = $(":input:text:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")");
            nextTextBox.focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Above code is working fine.

but, what I wish to do next is to auto highlight All text in the textbox. This is what I do:

```
$(function () {
    $('input:text:first').focus();
    var $inp = $('input:text');
    $inp.bind('keydown', function (e) {
        //var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode);
        var key = e.which;
        if (key == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var nxtIdx = $inp.index(this) + 1;
            var nextTextBox = $(":input:text:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")");
            nextTextBox.focus();
            nextTextBox.setSelectionRange(0, nextTextBox.value.length);
        }
    });
});
```

but, it's not working. Do you know how to patch the code for auto-highlighting all text after the focus jump to next textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(":input:text:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")")
```

this selector returns an array so you can either use [0] indexing or use val() to get the value which will return the first element matches to the selector.

You can use 
`$(":input:text:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")")[0]` or `$(":input:text:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")").val()`

```js
$(function() {
  $('input:text:first').focus();
  var $inp = $('input:text');
  $inp.bind('keydown', function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var nxtIdx = $inp.index(this) + 1;
      if ($(":input:text:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")").length > 0) {
        $(":input:text:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")").focus();
        $(":input:text:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")")[0].setSelectionRange(0, $(":input:text:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")")[0].value.length)
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<input />
```

Comment: It fixed. Thank you very much.

Comment: `$(input).select()` will automatically take care of `.focus(); .setSelectionRange(0,length);` https://jsfiddle.net/x0qtdLpz/

Comment: @Kaiido yes, that's nice suggestion